# не могу вывести информации с базы корректно

Tags: php, mysql

вопрос не сложный но я парюсь час над этим!

вот такой запрос на вывод даты с последующей группировкой GROUP date_on

выходят почти все даты кроме одной почему незнаю

```
echo "<select name='date_on'><option value=''>Выберите дату</option>";
// дата
$data_result=mysql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM user WHERE otd2='$otdl' AND tematiks='$tems' GROUP BY date_on"
);          // GROUP BY 'date_on'
$myrow_date=mysql_fetch_array($data_result);

while( $myrow_date=mysql_fetch_array($data_result) )
{
  printf(
    "<option value='%s'>%s</option>", $myrow_date['date_on'], $myrow_date['date_on']
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так вы убираете первую дату?

```
$myrow_date=mysql_fetch_array($data_result);
```

Уберите эту строку и всё будет хорошо)

Возможно более лучшим был-бы такой запрос:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date_on FROM user WHERE otd2 = '$otdl' AND tematiks = '$tems'
```

P.S. :

1. Ваши даты будут ( нужно быть готовым ) в случайном порядке, нужен хотя-бы `ORDER BY`
2. Зачем вы берёте все поля ( `*` ) если нужно только одно?
3. ИМХО: Имена переменных и столбцов - не несут смысловой нагрузки ( явной )

Comment: Вот блинн)) я час сижу))) Спасибо огромное